How to show that my Matrix is a M-Matrix
I consider a diagonal dominant matrix $A$, for which all non diagonal elements are zero or negative and all diagonal elements are positve. Moreover at least for one row $a_{ii}> \sum_{j \not = i}|a_{ij}|$ holds (for all other rows at least $a_{ii} \geq \sum_{j \not = i}|a_{ij}|$ holds in order to be diagonal dominant).
Two known results which however are not applicable in my case are the following:

if $A$ is irreducible and diagonal dominant i.e. $|a_{ii}| \geq  \sum_{j \not = i} |a_{ij}| \forall i$ than A is a M-Matrix.

if $A$ is strictly diagonal dominant than  A is a M-Matrix


The second result is not applicable in my context because my matrix is only strictly diagonal dominant for some rows. Furthermore I do not want to assume that my matrix is necessarily irreducible.
Can anyone help me to show that this type of matrix is always a M-Matrix ( I assume that this is true, if not you are welcome to state a counterexample)?
An example is the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Since the structure of my matrix is already in the correct form for an M-matrix, my approach is to show that all real eigenvalues of this type of matrix are positive. However, this is the point where I'm stuck at the moment.

I would like to understand the definitions better. According to Wikipedia an M-matrix is defined by closed sets (eigenvalues having nonnegative real parts, off-diagonal entries nonpositive). Then how come in the second bullet point the strict inequalities cannot be replaced with inclusive inequalities?

@zinsinho Without irreducibility, you don't have enough information to ensure that your matrix is invertible. A simple counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{2 & -1 & 0 & 0\
-1 & 2 & 0 & 0\
0& 0 & 1 & -1\
0& 0 & -1 & 1}.
$$

@Lieven From Googling, it appears that competing definitions exist. In this blog post for instance, M-matrices are non-singular by definition and M-matrices are defined by open sets.

Thanks @Ben Grossman. It would be helpful, then, to include the definition of an M-matrix in the question.

@BenGrossmann thanks for the counterexample! I hoped to show that these matrices can be categorized as M-matrices in order to guarantee that the inverse exists and that each entry of the inverse is zero or positive. It seems that I have to assume that A is irreducible to always guarantee this.

@BenGrossmann what If one require that each 'submatrix' should have at least one strictly diagonal dominant entry. For my underlying problem I investigate the underlying graphs and it holds true that each subgraph fulfills that property. Greetings Vincent

@zinsinho It's not clear what you mean by this condition. What does it mean for a submatrix to have "one strictly diagonal dominant entry"? Also, I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind when you say "submatrix".

@BenGrossmann sorry for the ambiguities! The counter example you proposed corresponds to a graph with two connected components (one corresponds to $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}  2 & -1 \ -1&  2 \end{bmatrix}$ and the other is $A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & -1 \ -1&  1 \end{bmatrix}$), which is totally fine for my set up. However, in my underlying problem each connected component will have at least one strictly diagonal dominant row, i.e. $A_2$ (which leads to the eigenvalue $0$) can not occur in my underlying problem. I read about Weakly chained diagonally dominant matrices, but its not the same.

@BenGrossmann So its more of: - if A is reducible every subgraph containing at least one spanning tree has at least one striclty diagonal dominant row (in all other the inequality is not strict). Is there a counter example for which the matrix is not invertible (are this kind of matrices M-matrices)?

@zinsinho Such a matrix will be invertible. If $A$ is block-diagonal or block upper triangular with square blocks on the diagonal, then $A$ is invertible if and only if every block along the diagonal is invertible. In your case, each of these matrices is invertible by your first “known result”.

A counterexample would necessarily have to be reducible. I believe that the following singular matrix satisfies all the hypotheses.
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

that's correct! (unfortunately for me) thank you for the counter example!
